# How can I tell SuperCSV that ignore line which has semi-column in it

Tags: csv, supercsv

I am using super CSV to parse CSV file in my portlet.

My CSV format is something like as below.

;A,BC,DE
;123
;xyz
;Instruction
;etc
Column1,Col2,col3
Val1,Val2

All I am interested in reading columns and value , I want to ignore anything above that or one which has semi-column in it.

How can I do that with help of SuperCSV ?

Thanks,
Sagar Vyas

Comment: Sorry for typo - I meant *semicolon instead of semi-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reply,

I am able to make it work with following code, which uses the [skip comments](http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/preferences.html#Skipping_comments) feature of Super CSV.

```
private static final CsvPreference STANDARD_SKIP_COMMENTS =    new CsvPreference.Builder(CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE).skipComments(new CommentStartsWith(";")).build();
 ICsvBeanReader beanReader = null;
beanReader = new CsvBeanReader(new FileReader(file), MyClass.STANDARD_SKIP_COMMENTS);
```

Thanks,
Sagar Vyas